# Convert Javascript string into name/value pair objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I convert the following sting into name/value pairs

```
id:"Ebene_1",version:"1.1",xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",x:"0px",y:"0px",xmlSpace:"preserve" d:"M8.5,23h-3C5.2,23,5,23.2,5,23.5S5.2,24,5.5,24h3C8.8,24,9,23.8,9,23.5S8.8,23,8.5,23z" height:"1",width:"3",x:"12",y:"28"
```

so that I can pass the result as a parameter to

```
createElem(type, attribs){
        this.svgElem = React.createElement(type,attribs)
        console.log(this.svgElem)
```

I thought about splitting it into an array on the comma but that will not work with the d: attribute

Any pointers gratefully received

Comment: Where does that string come from? Did you generate it yourself?

Comment: If you're getting that string from somewhere (which seems likely) it would probably be best  just to use the object itself as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Use this JavaScript method, `JSON.parse(string);`

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Why do you think that `string` is a valid JSON string and could be parsed?

Comment: We could add braces manually at the beginning and the end. In the string ,each key is separated by colon from its value, and pairs are delimited by comma, that's a typical JSON style.

Comment: @T.Liu, the keys must be quoted in JSON. This is not JSON.

Comment: Then, we could add double quotes after comma and before colon. The string is not JSON, but only needs very minor formatting changes to become JSON.

Comment: very long story but yes this string has been preformed by myself  because the svg data  given to me is not react friendly , I am just trying to strip out all the unnecessary attributes and then recreate the icon.

Comment: I'd recommend to transform the string into JSON. It won't take too much effort and will make it easy to understand for other developers. Also, we have many existing methods to process JSON, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your string is in the right format first. Then use `JSON.parse()`

```js
var string = '{"name": "bob", "age": "26"}';
var k = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(k);
```

Comment: see the other answer.

Comment: @zfrisch , Its still a valid answer

Comment: the project is more to do with acquiring the `string` value as valid JSON for parsing, and not so much the call to `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Sure, but the question asked was how to parse a string to an object

Answer (score 0):

Try with regular expressions:

```
var m, 
    result = {},
    re = /([a-z]+):("[^"]+")/gi,
    str = 'id:"Ebene_1",version:"1.1",xmlns:"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",x:"0px",y:"0px",xmlSpace:"preserve" d:"M8.5,23h-3C5.2,23,5,23.2,5,23.5S5.2,24,5.5,24h3C8.8,24,9,23.8,9,23.5S8.8,23,8.5,23z" height:"1",width:"3",x:"12",y:"28"';

do {
    m = re.exec(str);
    if (m) result[m[1]] = m[2];
} while (m);
console.log(result);
```

Output:

```
d: ""M8.5,23h-3C5.2,23,5,23.2,5,23.5S5.2,24,5.5,24h3C8.8,24,9,23.8,9,23.5S8.8,23,8.5,23z""
height: ""1""
id: ""Ebene_1""
xmlSpace: ""preserve""
version: ""1.1""
width: ""3""
x: ""12""
xmlns: ""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg""
y: ""28""
```

Comment: Thank you this works, but I will revisit my original data to see if Json could be used earlier

Comment: If you can export the data in JSON format, it would make things much simpler. However, I would advise not tinker with the string to make it json-like.

Comment: on first glance I thought this had worked, however if you look the regex is stripping  xmlS from the xmlSpace attribute, and my lowly regex experience cannot work out why.

Comment: I have updated my response. The regex is now case insensitive

Comment: Thank you I had narrowed it down to the S , but slow on how to fix it, still I know I know something new.